# Chrome extension with Youtube API showing inconsistent results

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

I'm building a chrome extension to work with youtube's API. This is how it works:

A content script is automatically injected on every youtube page via manifest.json

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_url>", "background"],
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://www.youtube.com/*"],
    "js": ["inject.js"]
  }
]
```

I have a lot of debugging points so I know the content script and listen.js gets loaded on every page.

With the content script I inject an extra piece of javascript code to listen to the player state. If the player state changes (paused, playing, ended, ...) it gets logged in the console.

```
// inject listen.js into current webpage
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("listen.js");
s.onload = function() {
   this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

Then, in listen.js I listen to youtube's player state.

```
var currentVideo = document.getElementById("movie_player");
currentVideo.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
function onytplayerStateChange() {
    console.log("state changed");
};
```

The only problem is that I can't get it to work consistently. Some Youtube pages give feedback on the player state, others don't. There's also no returning pattern. A youtube page that worked before could fail another time. Only if I reload the extension and open a youtube video in a new window, the player state gets logged in the console.

On the failing youtube pages the eventlistener in listen.js doesn't seem to be active. If i try to log the playerstate in the console this error shows up:

```
#<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'getPlayerState'
```

Any idea why I can't get consistent results? Is there something wrong with my permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the method "getPlayerState" was not firing because the video was not loaded yet.
To fix it, you just have to put the addEventListener inside a function called "onYouTubePlayerReady(playerID)" which is part of the YouTube javascript API.

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    var currentVideo = document.getElementById("movie_player");
    currentVideo.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange() {
  console.log("state changed");
};
```