# YouTube Data API returning inconsistent results with duplicates

Tags: youtube-api

There have been numerous questions about inconsistent results from the YouTube Data API: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516796/inconsistent-results-from-youtube-data-api-and-getting-150-error-code-while-play), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873799/inconsistent-youtube-api-v3-search-results), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71943981/getting-inconsistent-youtube-api-v3-results-when-using-pagination), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840996/chrome-extension-with-youtube-api-showing-inconsistent-results), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744056/youtube-data-api-search-not-returning-all-results), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71433464/youtube-data-api-search-list-return-unrealiable-result). Most of them have accepted answers that seem to indicate there was a problem with the API request that was fixed by the instructions in the answers. But none of those situations apply to the API request discussed here.

There have also been two questions about duplicates in the API results: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72082123/youtube-data-api-search-issue-next-page-results-contain-previous-pages-videos), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72438701/youtube-data-api-search-returning-repeating-items). Both of them have the same answer, which says to use the next-page token. But both questions say the token was used, so that answer is not helpful.

Yesterday, I submitted a series of API requests to get the list of most-viewed videos about 3D printing. The first request in the series was:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=3D print&type=video&maxResults=50&part=id,snippet&order=viewCount&key=<my key>
```

I ran that in a VBA sub, which took the next-page token from each result and resubmitted the URL with `&pageToken=<nextPageToken>` inserted.

The result was a list of 649 unique video IDs. So far so good.

After making some changes in the VBA code and seeing some duplicates in the result set, I went back today and ran the original VBA sub again. The result was again a list of 649 video IDs, but this time the list included duplicates and it also included IDs that were not in yesterday's list and was missing IDs that were there yesterday. Here is a comparison from the first two pages and the last two pages of the two result sets:

| Page | # on page | # overall | Run 1 | Run 2 | Same as | Seq | Dup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | [f2mdMcf-fJs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2mdMcf-fJs) | [f2mdMcf-fJs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2mdMcf-fJs) | 1 |  |  |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | [WSauz5KVKTU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSauz5KVKTU) | [WSauz5KVKTU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSauz5KVKTU) | 2 | Seq |  |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | [zsSCUWs7k9Q](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsSCUWs7k9Q) | [XYIUM5TkhMo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYIUM5TkhMo) | None |  |  |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | [B5Q1J5c8oNc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5Q1J5c8oNc) | [zsSCUWs7k9Q](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsSCUWs7k9Q) | 3 | Seq |  |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | [cUxIb3Pt-hQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUxIb3Pt-hQ) | [B5Q1J5c8oNc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5Q1J5c8oNc) | 4 | Seq |  |
| 1 | 6 | 6 | [4yyOOn7pWnA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yyOOn7pWnA) | [LDjE28szwr8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDjE28szwr8) | None |  |  |
| 1 | 7 | 7 | [3N46jQ0Xi3c](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3N46jQ0Xi3c) | [cUxIb3Pt-hQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUxIb3Pt-hQ) | 5 | Seq |  |
| 1 | 8 | 8 | [08dBVz8_VzU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08dBVz8_VzU) | [4yyOOn7pWnA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yyOOn7pWnA) | 6 | Seq |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 13 | 13 | [oeKIe1ik2O8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeKIe1ik2O8) | [e1rQ8YwNSDs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1rQ8YwNSDs) | 11 | Seq |  |
| 1 | 14 | 14 | [FrG_eSECfps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrG_eSECfps) | [RVB2JreIcoc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVB2JreIcoc) | 12 | Seq |  |
| 1 | 15 | 15 | [pPQCwz2q96o](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPQCwz2q96o) | [oeKIe1ik2O8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeKIe1ik2O8) | 13 | Seq |  |
| 1 | 16 | 16 | [uo3KuoEiu3I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uo3KuoEiu3I) | [pPQCwz2q96o](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPQCwz2q96o) | 15 | NOT |  |
| 1 | 17 | 17 | [0U6aIwd5h9s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U6aIwd5h9s) | [uo3KuoEiu3I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uo3KuoEiu3I) | 16 | Seq |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 47 | 47 | [ShGsW68zbIo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShGsW68zbIo) | [iu9rhqsvrPs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iu9rhqsvrPs) | 46 | Seq |  |
| 1 | 48 | 48 | [0q0xS7W78KQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0q0xS7W78KQ) | [ShGsW68zbIo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShGsW68zbIo) | 47 | Seq |  |
| 1 | 49 | 49 | [UheJQsXOAnY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UheJQsXOAnY) | [0q0xS7W78KQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0q0xS7W78KQ) | 48 | Seq | Dup |
| 1 | 50 | 50 | [H8AcqOh0wis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8AcqOh0wis) | [H8AcqOh0wis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8AcqOh0wis) | 50 | NOT | Dup |
| 2 | 1 | 51 | [EWq3-2VuqbQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWq3-2VuqbQ) | [0q0xS7W78KQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0q0xS7W78KQ) | 48 | NOT | Dup |
| 2 | 2 | 52 | [scuTZza4f_o](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scuTZza4f_o) | [H8AcqOh0wis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8AcqOh0wis) | 50 | NOT | Dup |
| 2 | 3 | 53 | [bJWJW-mz4_U](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJWJW-mz4_U) | [UheJQsXOAnY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UheJQsXOAnY) | 49 | NOT |  |
| 2 | 4 | 54 | [Ii4VYsh9OlM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ii4VYsh9OlM) | [EWq3-2VuqbQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWq3-2VuqbQ) | 51 | NOT |  |
| 2 | 5 | 55 | [r2-OGUu57pU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2-OGUu57pU) | [scuTZza4f_o](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scuTZza4f_o) | 52 | Seq |  |
| 2 | 6 | 56 | [8KTnu18Mi9Q](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KTnu18Mi9Q) | [bJWJW-mz4_U](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJWJW-mz4_U) | 53 | Seq |  |
| 2 | 7 | 57 | [DconsfGsXyA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DconsfGsXyA) | [Ii4VYsh9OlM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ii4VYsh9OlM) | 54 | Seq |  |
| 2 | 8 | 58 | [UttEvLJP3l8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UttEvLJP3l8) | [8KTnu18Mi9Q](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KTnu18Mi9Q) | 56 | NOT |  |
| 2 | 9 | 59 | [GJOOLH9ZP2I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJOOLH9ZP2I) | [DconsfGsXyA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DconsfGsXyA) | 57 | Seq |  |
| 2 | 10 | 60 | [ewgmg9Q5Ab8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewgmg9Q5Ab8) | [UttEvLJP3l8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UttEvLJP3l8) | 58 | Seq |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 13 | 35 | 635 | [qHpR_p8lA4I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHpR_p8lA4I) | [FFVOzo7tSV8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFVOzo7tSV8) | 639 | Seq |  |
| 13 | 36 | 636 | [DplwDDZNTRc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DplwDDZNTRc) | [76IBjdM9s6g](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76IBjdM9s6g) | 640 | Seq |  |
| 13 | 37 | 637 | [3AObqGsimr8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AObqGsimr8) | [qEh0uZuu7_U](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEh0uZuu7_U) | None |  |  |
| 13 | 38 | 638 | [88keQ4PWH18](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88keQ4PWH18) | [RhfGJduOlrw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhfGJduOlrw) | 641 | Seq |  |
| 13 | 39 | 639 | [FFVOzo7tSV8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFVOzo7tSV8) | [QxzH9QkirCU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxzH9QkirCU) | 643 | NOT |  |
| 13 | 40 | 640 | [76IBjdM9s6g](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76IBjdM9s6g) | [Qsgz4GbL8O4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qsgz4GbL8O4) | None |  |  |
| 13 | 41 | 641 | [RhfGJduOlrw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhfGJduOlrw) | [BSgg7mEzfqY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSgg7mEzfqY) | 644 | Seq |  |
| 13 | 42 | 642 | [lVEqwV0Nlzg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVEqwV0Nlzg) | [VcmjbJ2q8-w](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcmjbJ2q8-w) | 645 | Seq |  |
| 13 | 43 | 643 | [QxzH9QkirCU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxzH9QkirCU) | [gOU0BCL-TXs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOU0BCL-TXs) | None |  |  |
| 13 | 44 | 644 | [BSgg7mEzfqY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSgg7mEzfqY) | [IoOXQUcW24s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IoOXQUcW24s) | 646 | Seq |  |
| 13 | 45 | 645 | [VcmjbJ2q8-w](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcmjbJ2q8-w) | [o4_2_a6LzFU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4_2_a6LzFU) | 647 | Seq | Dup |
| 14 | 1 | 646 | [IoOXQUcW24s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IoOXQUcW24s) | [o4_2_a6LzFU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4_2_a6LzFU) | 647 | NOT | Dup |
| 14 | 2 | 647 | [o4_2_a6LzFU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4_2_a6LzFU) | [ijVPcGaqVjc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijVPcGaqVjc) | 648 | Seq |  |
| 14 | 3 | 648 | [ijVPcGaqVjc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijVPcGaqVjc) | [nk3FlgEuG-s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nk3FlgEuG-s) | 649 | Seq |  |
| 14 | 4 | 649 | [nk3FlgEuG-s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nk3FlgEuG-s) | [27ZLFn8Dejg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27ZLFn8Dejg) | None |  |  |

The last three columns have the following meanings:

- **Same as:** If an ID from Run 2 is the same as an ID from Run 1, then this column has the `# overall` for Run 1.
- **Seq:** Indicates whether the number in column "Same as" is one more than the previous number in that column.
- **Dup:** Indicates whether an ID from Run 2 occurred more than once in that run.

Problems:

- The videos [XYIUM5TkhMo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYIUM5TkhMo), [LDjE28szwr8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDjE28szwr8), [qEh0uZuu7_U](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEh0uZuu7_U), [Qsgz4GbL8O4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qsgz4GbL8O4), [gOU0BCL-TXs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOU0BCL-TXs), and [27ZLFn8Dejg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27ZLFn8Dejg) were returned as #3, 6, 637, 640, 643, and 649 in Run 2, but were not returned at all in Run 1.
- The videos [FrG_eSECfps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrG_eSECfps), [r2-OGUu57pU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2-OGUu57pU), [lVEqwV0Nlzg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVEqwV0Nlzg)  were returned as #14, 55, 642, in Run 1, but were not in Run 2.
- The videos [0q0xS7W78KQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0q0xS7W78KQ), [H8AcqOh0wis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8AcqOh0wis), and [o4_2_a6LzFU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4_2_a6LzFU) were returned as #49, 50, and 645 in Run 2, but then each appears a second time in that run (as well as appearing in Run 1 as #48, 50, and 647).

These results are troubling. They mean that no single search will return a reliable list of videos for a given value of `q`.

I mentioned at the beginning that previous questions about inconsistent results from the YouTube Data API had answers that seemed to resolve those inconsistencies. Is there a way to do that for this search? Is there something wrong with the way I'm composing the search that is causing the problem?

If there isn't a way to fix the search, then I suppose the only way to get a list of videos on the topic with high confidence of it being complete is to run the search multiple times and merge the results until no new IDs appear that were not in a previous result set. But even then, one would not know if there are other videos lurking undetected.

Comment: 1/3 Note that [`type="video"`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) should be `type=video` ([I modified your question accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74450557/revisions)). I noticed that using [the YouTube UI](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=3D+print&sp=CAMSAhAB) I got the same results as **Run 2** up to [`LDjE28szwr8`](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/LDjE28szwr8) but the next video was [`29PNv3hG_IA`](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/29PNv3hG_IA) instead of [`cUxIb3Pt-hQ`](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/cUxIb3Pt-hQ).

Comment: 2/3 Note that `29PNv3hG_IA` isn't in your results while it was published 2 years ago. A problem here is that for a given video we don't know if for a given query parameter value, even as a very high rank, the video should appear in the query results (related to [this problem](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/4)).

Comment: 3/3 Please deepen YouTube UI results and let me know if [proposing *all at a time*](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/c309312ad2369ba9287a2c882cf48992865dd229/search.php#L105-L133) parameters [`q`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#q), `type=video` and [`order=viewCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#order) for a search query in my reverse-engineered YouTube UI [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API) [API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com) would help you.

Comment: I watched the same problem on the YouTube website. Best you can do is post a ticket on Issue Tracker or remove duplicates once detected.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison - I've checked out your API and done some test runs. Very interesting, and I can share the results with you. I've sent you a message through the Matrix contact link on your API and GitHub pages.

Comment: I answered you on Matrix that *I think sharing your results by editing your StackOverflow question would be the better way to share with anybody the current state of the art concerning your problem.*

Comment: Its been bug reported [35177262](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35177262)