# (React.JS)Youtube Api nextpagetoken intermittent return duplicated video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api

when I use "GET [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search%22) with nextpagetoken,

intermittent return duplicate video

for instance,

*maxResult:5*

**first call(without nextpagetoken)**

get  {videoID : a} , {videoID : b} , {videoID : c} , **{videoID : d}**  , {videoID : e}

and than

**second call (with nextpagetoken)**

get **{videoID : d}** , {videoID : f} , {videoID : g} , {videoID : h} , {videoID : i}

I expect {videoID : f} , {videoID : g} , {videoID : h} , {videoID : i} , {videoID : j}

this is the problem!!

I wanted the list to constructed like [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]

**but**

list constructed like [a,b,c,**d**,e,**d**,f,g,h,i]

At first I thought a problem comes up when I set called api data on List.

but duplicate data has been called! and already duplicate data on List.

and also This problem does not always occur, but it often happens.

**Am I write something wrong code to cause this problem(intermittent return duplicate result)?**

Thanks to read long and rough question.

Comment: Unfortunately [your question has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74450557).

Comment: Its been bug reported [35177262](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35177262)